# How X is getting value in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular.js just working on a function `ng-repeat`. in which i am using `ng-repeat="x in name"` where i have defines some values in `names` but i didn't defines x anywhere in complete code.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
    ];
});
</script>
```

Everything is working fine but i wonder how the values are coming in `x` or what exactly `ng-repeat` is doing here as i am just calling `x` but not defining any value in `x`.

Comment: `ng-repeat` directive is working as `for in` loop in javascript.

Comment: `ng-repeat` is like a foreach loop or like @RohitJindal said a `for in`. It loop object by object in a array of object so `x` take the value of each object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is being defined by angular's `ng-repeat` directive. It is iterating over all the values in `names` and binding each value to `x` in turn.

Note that you can choose any other valid variable name instead of `x`.

The reason there is no conflict between each value of `x` is that each iteration gets its own `$scope`.

See also the [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: so m i forced to use x in `ng-repeat` or i can use any other variable??

Comment: You can change `x` to any other valid variable name and each value in `names` will be then instantiated to a variable with the name you chose.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` directive is working same as `for in` loop in javascript.

`ng-repeat="x in names"` means you are iterating every index of `names` array.

```
$scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
    ];
```

**Both are same :**

```
for (var X in $scope.names) {
   console.log($scope.names[X].name + ',' + $scope.names[X].country);
}
```

and

```
ng-repeat="x in names"
```

x is defined in angular's `ng-repeat` directive.

Answer (score 1):

I went to see the code at [git-hub ng-repeat.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/85db30a3be7918e2159b799fec190c1836b751ad/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js)

Ng-repeat works by watching the reference to the collection that we specified using this code that ignore every property that starts with a $.

```
     for (var itemKey in collection) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(collection, itemKey) && itemKey.charAt(0)  !== '$') {
            collectionKeys.push(itemKey);
        }
     }
```

and during the compile this happens:

```
  var match = expression.match(/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s*$/);
```

this will separate the words in your ng-repeat value in SOMETHING in COLLECTION and possibly with some TRACKBY in the end.
So a variable is created within ngRepeat directive to iterate over our collection that is being watched using a `watchCollection` watch.

The SOMETHING will be defined inside the scope of the ngRepeat directive. 
The COLLECTION will actually be a reference from the user $scope.
You can almost pick anyname you want for SOMETHING, but not for COLLECTION.

Comment: Angular grabs the definition of it, parses the string in 2 grabs the first and creates a variable with the same name that will serve as cursor during the $digest phase to scroll over the second object that is defined in the user scope. The variable doesn't stay accessible because it is created just to to run the repeat. I am making this up,  it should work like this.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` will iterate over your `names` array.
Each object that it iterates over is represented by the name you give it in your template - in your case - `x`.
You can give it any name you'd like and it will represent an object from the selected array.